# name "ClassName" is not defined even though im sure i imported correctly (Python)

Tags: python, pygame, nameerror

I'm stuck at an error where U get a name error even though I'm sure I imported correctly. So I'm trying to create a class instance from one file referring to the other. The imports in the main file looks like this

```
from movement import *
from maps import *
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init() 

# Player class is in the movement file
player1 = Player(300, 300, 50, 50, 50)
```

this is the movement file

```
from maps import *
from main import *
import pygame

pygame.init()

objectAmount = 0


class Player:
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, width, height, speed):
         self.pos_x = pos_x
         self.pos_y = pos_y
         self.speed = speed
         self.width = width
         self.height = height
         self.player_image = pygame.image.load("Munir.png")
         self.image_rect = self.player_image.get_rect()
```

I have tried to use `import movement` and `from movement import Player`
without succeeding to solve the problem. I'm guessing that the problem lies in me importing several files maybe? U have no clue. Following is the error message

> NameError: name 'Player' is not defined

Comment: which python version do you use? you may add the __init__.py

Comment: I use Python 3.6.4, I will look up init.py thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you're importing main again in your movements file.
It's caused because importing a file is basically running it, so when you run main.py, you import movements.py, and one of the first things you do is import main again. There are some features in python that allow circular imports, which is why it doesn't import moments again causing an infinite loop.  So python doesn't import movements again, but tires to create a Player instance, however Player hasn't been defined yet.

You have two solutions, either do not import main from your movements file, or move your  `player1 = Player(300, 300, 50, 50, 50)` into a class + method of it's own. Such as a MainGame class with a run() method. Or move them in a block like:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    player1 = Player(300, 300, 50, 50, 50)
    #... main loop of your game.
```

That condition is a simple condition that is only true when you're running a python file, rather than importing it.

That way you can define some things in your main.py that can be used in movements. However, it's best to not use circular importing.

FYI it's usful to look at the stack trace, here you can see how it went from main, into movements, then back into main and caused the error, rather then importing movements, then continued to run inside of main.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from movement import *
  File "/home/user/temp/so/movement.py", line 2, in <module>
    from main import *
  File "/home/user/temp/so/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    player1 = Player(300, 300, 50, 50, 50)
NameError: name 'Player' is not defined
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'l try to circumvent the circle loop!